# Create floating window in android 9.0 API 28

Tags: java, android, xml

**Edit** ((
I found the error, the error occurs when I try to add this line

```
mwindow.addView (img,parmas);
```

Does anyone have an idea why?))

I'm trying to create floating window in Android 9.0 API 28
put i get the same error evry time i try
The app cloces when i do this
this is my code for FloatingWindow.java

```
public class FloatingWindow extends Service  {
private WindowManager mwindow;
private ImageView img;
@Override
Public IBinder onBind (Intent intent){
//TODO: Retur the communication chanel to the servic.
throw new UnsupportedOperationException ("Not yet implemented")
}
public void onCreate (){
img = new ImageView (this);
img.setImageResource (R.drawable.imgicon);
mwindow = (WindowManager)getSystemService (WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams  (
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTECT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICTION_OVERLAY,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
mwindow.addView (img,params);
}
}
```

In MainActivity i have one button to called with FloatinWindow;

```
button.setOnClickLidtener (new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override 
public void onClick (View v){
startService (new Intent (MainActivity.this,FloatingWindow.class));
}
});
```

In mainfest.XML i added

```
<service
android:name=".FloatinWindow"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"></service>

<uses-permission android:name"android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW/>
```

Finally
For the **type** of WindowManager.LayoutParams 
I used **TYPE_PHONE & TYPE_TOAST**
and get the same error

Can anyone help my 
Thanks.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Thanks. Do you have another way ?!

Comment: I found the error ,the error occurs when i add this line  mwindow.addView (img,params); do you know why?!